# Migrate application developed with the Provisioning API to the new api (Admin SDK)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-sdk

Reviewing the new api (Admin SDK) [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/). I found the following problem, none of these APIs have support 2 legged for the google apps marketplace, there is a way to integrate these new apis or if in the future the google apps marketplace will support for OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admin SDK APIs function with Two Legged OAuth just fine, I'm using the Directory API in my marketplace app today. You'll need to go into your Vendor Profile page on the marketplace, click "Register for additional APIs" and enable Admin SDK. You'll also need to add the needed API scopes to your manifest.

Also note that the [google-api-python-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) at least does not support OAuth 1.0 any longer so you'll need to either perform the authentication manually or utilize the old GData library to get the correct auth headers.