# Rails Signet Client & Admin SDK/Directory API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the Google Signet Client in a Rails app to access Google APIs, right now the Provisioning API mostly, through OAuth 1. Google just came out with a new set of APIs under the Admin SDK moniker. Specifically, I'm interested in a function of the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). Unfortunately, the Directory API keeps returning an 'Invalid Credentials' response through the signet client.

Authentication for my OAuth happens through Google Marketplace to do keys and whatnot. Here's a sample on how the code generates the client:

```
oauth_args = {
  :authorization_uri => "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
  :token_credential_uri =>"https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken",
  :client_credential_key => < google_marketplace_consumer_key >,
  :client_credential_secret => < google_marketplace_consumer_secret >
}

client = Signet::OAuth1::Client.new(oauth_args)
client.two_legged = true
client.requestor_id = self.owner.email
client.get(:uri=>'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key=<api key>&domain=< my test domain >')
```

Oddly, this same request works just fine through the OAuth1 playground, using the same test keys that I use in my local environment, but everytime I hit the Directory API I get the same 'Invalid Credentials'. Also note that, save for the URL being requested, this is the same code that I use to hit the Provisioning API.

Anyone know why this API specifically seems to have a problem with either the client or how I'm auth'ing? I have enabled the API for my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had nothing to do with the signet client in the end, but just with the Google Marketplace permissions; the 'Invalid Credentials' error was more of a red herring. Did the steps listed at [Migrate application developed with the Provisioning API to the new api (Admin SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727017/migrate-application-developed-with-the-provisioning-api-to-the-new-api-admin-sd) and it worked; I had enabled the API for my app, but hadn't updated the manifest.